Any ultraweakly continuous functional is completely additive
Hi I am stuck in the proof of the following fact that the book Lectures on von Neumann Algebras by Serban V. Stratila and Laszlo Zsido quotes at page 117 (before Lemma 5.7):

Obviously, any $w$-continuous form on $\mathscr{M}$ is completely additive.

Here, a bounded form $\varphi$ on a vNa is said to be completely bounded if, for any family $\{e_i\}_i$ of mutually orthogonal projections in $\mathscr{M}$, one has
$$
\varphi (\sum_i e_i) = \sum_i \varphi(e_i).
$$
and the $w$-topology (or ultraweak topology) on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is the weak topology $\sigma(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}), \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_*)$ where
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_*:= \overline{\text{span} \{ \omega_{\xi, \eta} : \xi, \eta \in \mathcal{H}} \}.
$$
I have managed to prove that for any $\xi, \eta \in \mathcal{H}$ the functional $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$ is completely additive and thus this is true for any functional from their span. But for a general $\omega \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})_*$ the proof doesn't work: Let $(e_i)_i$ be an orthogonal family of projections. Choose $(\omega_k)_k$ be a net in that span such that $\omega = \lim_k \omega_k$. But then we get
$$
\omega\left(\sum_i e_i\right) = \lim_k \omega_k\left( \sum_i e_i \right)= \lim_k \sum_i \omega_k(e_i)
$$
now how can I interchange the lim with the sum? Any help

This is an issue of uniform convergence, where the crucial observation is that the sum of any orthogonal family of projections is a projection and thus has norm $1$. Indeed, the equation $\omega(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) = \sum_{i \in I} \omega(e_i)$ means, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists finite $I_0 \subset I$ s.t. $|\omega(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega(e_i)| < \epsilon$. Choose $\omega'$ in the span of $\omega_{\xi, \eta}$ s.t. $\|\omega - \omega'\| < \epsilon/3$. Since you have already proved the result for $\omega'$, there exists finite $I_0 \subset I$ s.t. $|\omega'(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega'(e_i)| < \epsilon/3$. Thus,
$$\begin{split}
&|\omega(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega(e_i)|\\
\leq &|\omega(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \omega'(\sum_{i \in I} e_i)| + |(\sum_{i \in I_0} \omega(e_i)) - (\sum_{i \in I_0} \omega'(e_i))| + |\omega'(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega'(e_i)|\\
= &|(\omega - \omega')(\sum_{i \in I} e_i)| + |(\omega - \omega')(\sum_{i \in I_0} e_i)| + |\omega'(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega'(e_i)|\\
\leq &\|\omega - \omega'\|\|\sum_{i \in I} e_i\| + \|\omega - \omega'\|\|\sum_{i \in I_0} e_i\| + |\omega'(\sum_{i \in I} e_i) - \sum_{i \in I_0} \omega'(e_i)|\\
< &\epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3\\
= &\epsilon
\end{split}$$

Can the downvoter explain what exactly is the problem with this answer?
